# Remove all attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove all attributes at once using jQuery?

```
<img src="example.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

to

```
<img>
```

I tried `$('img').removeAttr('*');` with no luck. Anyone?

Comment: Bad idea, you should only remove what attributes you know about, a DOM element has a lot more attributes than what you specify in the tag each with their own default or calculated value.

Comment: I tried to use user993683 answer in Vue. It worked, but afterward my styles were acting weird. I checked the attributes and there was one named data-v. Turns out Vue uses this to apply scoped styles. It didn't take me long to find the problem, but I would be carful when using one of these solutions. Especially, when using frameworks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Update:** the previous method works in IE8 but not in IE8 compatibility mode and previous versions of IE. So here is a version that does and uses jQuery to remove the attributes as it does a better job of it:

```
$("img").each(function() {
  // first copy the attributes to remove
  // if we don't do this it causes problems
  // iterating over the array we're removing
  // elements from
  var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
    return item.name;
  });

  // now use jQuery to remove the attributes
  var img = $(this);
  $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
    img.removeAttr(item);
  });
});
```

Of course you could [make a plug-in](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) out of it:

```
jQuery.fn.removeAttributes = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });
    var img = $(this);
    $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
    img.removeAttr(item);
    });
  });
}
```

and then do:

```
$("img").removeAttributes();
```

Comment: No need for a plugin, it was the while loop I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Err, no. This doesn't come close to a working solution for IE. `removeAttribute` does not work at all like you expect here (hint: that `while` loop is gonna lock up the poor browser forever).

Comment: just came across this - I wish u could lock up IE forever across all computers at once, and only allow one tab to work, which points to the Chrome download page. That would be awesome! (and no, I don't mean allow IE 9 or 10 - IE 6 was / **still is** so rubbish that IE 9 and 10 deserve to suffer!)

Comment: By the way this came in very very useful today - just taken this as the basis for my plugin and passed options into the function (with defaults using `$.extend`) so that I can say I want to remove all attributes from these elements, besides these attributes (name, id, class etc. go here). Attributes are accepted as an object, array or string (which is split on comma).

Comment: What for you run 2 loops (map and each)? It's performance inefficient when it's required to remove attributes from a mass of elements. You can easily combine these into a single loop: `$.each(this.attributes, function(i, item) { img.removeAttr(item.name) });`

Comment: @manakor the reason why 1 loop wont work is because removeAttr alters this.attributes, thereby breaking the iteration and finding "item" is undefined. I just tried it.

Comment: @ZeroGravityChimp start looping from the end of attributes array to avoid skipping elements due to the changing length: `for (var i = this.attributes.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) { img.removeAttr(this.attributes[i].name); }`

Comment: @manakor +1 for altering your code to make it work. Personally, though, I wouldn't use this because its simpler and easier to maintain 2 separated for loops with exact purposes. eg if you decide later to comment that line out your application will enter an infinite loop. Loops that change what they are looping over are dangerous in my opinion.

Comment: @manakor Woops sorry not infinite loop. That part of my comment is totally wrong. Just suggesting that to avoid errors its better to pull out the iteration list specifically instead of alter the collection as you go.

Answer (score 83):

A simple method that doesn't require JQuery:

```
while(elem.attributes.length > 0)
    elem.removeAttribute(elem.attributes[0].name);
```

Comment: Be careful if you selected a JQuery object. You need to convert it to htmlElement ([$elem.get(0)](https://api.jquery.com/get/)) before using this method.

Comment: I'm not sure why all examples contain something like "elem.attributes.length" In my opinion a bit faster is something like:

while (elem.attributes[0]) {
  elem.attributes.removeNamedItem(elem.attributes[0].name);                
}

Answer (score 18):

One-liner, no jQuery needed:

```
[...elem.attributes].forEach(attr => elem.removeAttribute(attr.name));
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a new `jQuery.fn.removeAttributes` (demonstrated in the accepted answer) you can extend jQuery's existing [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) method making it accept zero parameters to remove all attributes from each element in a set:

```
var removeAttr = jQuery.fn.removeAttr;
jQuery.fn.removeAttr = function() {

  if (!arguments.length) {
    this.each(function() {

      // Looping attributes array in reverse direction
      // to avoid skipping items due to the changing length
      // when removing them on every iteration.
      for (var i = this.attributes.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        jQuery(this).removeAttr(this.attributes[i].name);
      }
    });

    return this;
  }

  return removeAttr.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Now you can call `.removeAttr()` without parameters to remove all attributes from the element:

```
$('img').removeAttr();
```

Answer (score 1):

One very good reason to do this for specific tags is to clean up legacy content and also enforce standards.

Let's say, for example, you wanted to remove legacy attributes, or limit damage caused by FONT tag attributes by stripping them.

I've tried several methods to achieve this and none, including the example above, work as desired.

Example 1: Replace all FONT tags with the contained textual content.
This would be the perfect solution but as of v1.6.2 has ceased to function. :(

```
$('#content font').each(function(i) {
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Example 2: Strip all attributes from a named tag - e.g. FONT.
Again, this fails to function but am sure it used to work once upon a previous jQuery version.

```
$("font").each(function() {
 // First copy the attributes to remove.
 var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
   return item.name;
 });     
 // Now remove the attributes
 var font = $(this);
 $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
   $("font").removeAttr(item);
 });
});
```

Looking forward to 1.7 which promises to include a method to remove multiple attributes by name.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner.

### For jQuery users

```
$('img').removeAttr(Object.values($('img').get(0).attributes).map(attr => attr.name).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

One don't need to refer to the name of attribute to to id nowadays, since we have
[removeAttributeNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttributeNode) method.

```
while(elem.attributes.length > 0) {
    elem.removeAttributeNode(elem.attributes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're using it for, but have you considered using css classes instead and toggling those ? It'll be less coding on your side and less work for the browser to do. This will probably not work [easily] if you're generating some of the attributes on the fly like with and height.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all attributes and it will work for every type of element.

```
    var x = document.createElement($("#some_id").prop("tagName"));
    $(x).insertAfter($("#some_id"));
    $("#some_id").remove();
```

Comment: This also removes event bindings.

Comment: Then reason for down voting ?

Answer (score -1):

Today I have same issue. I think that it will be useful for you

```js
var clone = $(node).html();
clone = $('<tr>'+ clone +'</tr>');
clone.addClass('tmcRow');
```