# how to remove all attributes from <body> with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

how to remove all attributes from  with js or jquery.
(I don't know what is the attributes in the body, i want remove all them)

Comment: What is your end goal by doing this?

Comment: @meder: I can only assume that he can't control the output of the page he's controlling.

Comment: Somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: @meder - while the end goal doesn't matter at all, my end goal is complex PJAX handling. there are countless reasons for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the DOM Level 1 Core `attributes` property to access attributes as a list. As plain JS:

```
function removeAllAttrs(element) {
    for (var i= element.attributes.length; i-->0;)
        element.removeAttributeNode(element.attributes[i]);
}
removeAllAttrs(document.body);
```

Or dressed up in jQuery plugin clothes:

```
$.fn.removeAllAttrs= function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            this.ownerElement.removeAttributeNode(this);
        });
    });
};

$('body').removeAllAttrs();
```

Comment: Does this work in IE? In IE `attributes` contains all possible attribute names, regardless of whether they've been set, and I wondered if that could cause problems. Haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Array-like access to `attributes` does seem to work, independently of the issues with property-name access.

Comment: Instead of creating a new `$.fn.removeAllAttrs` you can extend jQuery's existing `.removeAttr()` method making it accept zero parameters to remove all attributes from each element: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28761247/309031

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to remove the attributes to `element`, you can use something like

```
$(element).removeAttr($.makeArray(element.attributes)
                       .map(function(item){ return item.name;})
                       .join(' '));
```

Note that this will work only with jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 2):

As of ES2015, you can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
const el = document.body;
const attributes = Array.from(el.attributes);
attributes.forEach(attr => el.removeAttributeNode(attr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $newBody = $('<body>');
$newBody.append( $('body').contents() );
$('body').replaceWith( $newBody );
```

Something like this might work.

Comment: Replacing the `body` has the side-effect of losing any JavaScript/jQuery references pointing to it, though, including any event handlers on it.

Comment: onclick, etc. are attributes from an XHTML viewpoint. Furthermore, it's trivial to make sure this runs before any other jQuery event binding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way but it works

```
$('body').each(function(){
     var $body = $(this);
     var attributes = $.makeArray(this.attributes);

     $.each(attributes, function(indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
         $body.removeAttr(valueOfElement.name);
     });
});
```

Comment: Is "each" really necessary here?