# Remove all html attributes with regex (replace)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

For example i have such html:

```
<title>Ololo - text’s life</title><div class="page-wrap"><div class="ng-scope"><div class="modal custom article ng-scope in" id="new-article" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-dialog first-modal-wrapper">< div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body full long"><div class="form-group">olololo<ul style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><li>texttext</li><li>Filter the events lists by host.</li><li>Create graphs for separate hosts and for the groups of hosts.</li></ul><p style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">bbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvb</p></div></div></div></div></div></div><title>cvbcbcvbcvbcvbccb</title><div class="page-wrap"></div></div>
```

how could i remove all style class id etc from such html?

i have such regex:

```
/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i
```

what is wrong? how to delete all html attributes with the help of regex?

here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qL4maxn0/1/

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with regexs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  (Unless it's very limited, known html)

Comment: @JamesThorpe no other way here(((

Comment: What @jamesthorpe says is right. If you want to do this, edit your html or - in the worst case if you _have to_ - remove each with javascript...

Comment: There's always another way =D

Comment: @bwegs attr not tags

Comment: @Huangism attr not tags –

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I don't know what you are talking about, I only removed tag from the title

Comment: what is wrong with javascript's `removeAttribute`?

Comment: @Mr_Green becouse from json i get html string

Comment: @brabertaser1992 check my answer below. that will work for json objects too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I would advise you **not to use regexes in this situation**, they are not meant to parse tree-shaped structures like HTML.

If you however don't have a choice, I think for the requested problem, you can use a regex.

Looks to me like you forgot spaces, accents, etc. You can use the fact that the greater than `>` and less than `<` signs are not allowed as raw text.

```
/<\s*([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\s.*?>/gi
```

and call it with:

```
result = body.replace(regex, '<$1>')
```

For your given sample, it produces:

```
<title>Ololo - text’s life</title><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>olololo<ul><li>texttext</li><li>Filter the events lists by host.</li><li>Create graphs for separate hosts and for the groups of hosts.</li></ul><p>bbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvb</p></div></div></div></div></div></div><title>cvbcbcvbcvbcvbccb</title><div></div></div>
```

Comment: @brabertaser1992: modified... better?

Comment: @brabertaser1992: although I'm wondering if it is valid html to write a space between the opening tag `<` and the tag name...

Comment: sure that nov valid) but maybe user is inValid and make some mistake)

Comment: one last question: good, just how to leave src for images or href for a tags etc? only href and src?
thank you
yes, i know: regex are the worst part by me)

Comment: @brabertaser1992: in that case I really would not use regexes. Is there no way you can use a DOM parser or anything? Almost all regexes will have shortcomings and eventually fail on such replacements...

Comment: from json i get html string  - DOM i din't think so

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wR5wC4/1   -  so it didn't get all classes styles etc, for example with multiple classes... what i do wrong?

Comment: Looks to me, spaces should be allowed as well, thus: `style\s*=\s*"[^"]*` will probably work

Answer (score 4):

You should not use regex here.

```
var html = '<title>Ololo - text’s life</title><div class="page-wrap"><div class="ng-scope"><div class="modal custom article ng-scope in" id="new-article" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-dialog first-modal-wrapper"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body full long">                        <div class="form-group">olololo<ul style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><li>texttext</li><li>Filter the events lists by host.</li><li>Create graphs for separate hosts and for the groups of hosts.</li>                            </ul><p style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">bbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvbcvb</p></div><div></div></div></div></div><title>cvbcbcvbcvbcvbccb</title><div class="page-wrap"></div></div>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;

function removeAllAttrs(element) {
    for (var i = element.attributes.length; i-- > 0;)
    element.removeAttributeNode(element.attributes[i]);
}

function removeAttributes(el) {
    var children = el.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        removeAllAttrs(child);
        if (child.children.length) {
            removeAttributes(child);
        }
    }
}
removeAttributes(div);
console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3to6o24s/1/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3593250/1577396)

Comment: I recommend using `documentFragment` instead of a `div`, but that's just an implementation detail.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for the info (_I was not aware of this_). Somehow I am not able to get the result if I do so.

Comment: You can't just drop in [document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) as a replacement for `div` elements, but the idea is that the `div` adds context as a `body` element, where the document fragment is context free and may represent *any* fragment of HTML.

Comment: I think using `div` is a vector for XSS, eg if someone tried `<img src="invalidurl" onerror="alert('xss');">`.  Assume that since a document fragment is context free, it wouldn't try to load the image (and hence fire the JS) as soon as you add the html to it?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `g` flag to make the replace global.

```
/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/ig
```

Also, if you're doing this for security purposes, look into using a proper HTML sanitizer : [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wR5wC4/1   -  so it didn't get all classes styles etc, for example with multiple classes... what i do wrong?

Comment: @brabertaser1992, Yeah.  I was pointing out why your original regex doesn't work on multiple tags.  But there are other problems.  For example, `<img title="2>1 onerror=alert(42) "">">` will split through.  See comments above on trying to parse HTML with regexs without reading the language specification first.