# How to remove attributes at a time using jquery

Tags: jquery

$('#myImage').removeAttr('class').removeAttr('style').removeAttr('border');

That one works just fine but is there a way to remove a set of attributes from an element?

I altered the code a bit, like

```
$.fn.removeAttrs = function () {
    // Convert all passed arguments to an array
    var args = arguments[0].split(' '),
        attr;

    // Loop, removing the first array item on each iteration
    while (attr = args.shift())
        this.removeAttr(attr);

    // Return the jQuery object for chaining
    return this;
}
```

call it like below

```
$('#myImage').removeAttrs('class style border');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870441/remove-all-attributes)

Comment: @RPM1984: that's not quite the same; this question is asking to remove *some*, not *all* attributes so the answers will be fundamentally different.

Comment: Yes - i was going to post an answer but figured in that Q @cletus' answer was great, and all it would take would be a 1 liner for the OP (pass through the list of attributes to remove).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you could write your own easily enough:

```
$.fn.removeAttrs = function () {
    // Convert all passed arguments to an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        attr;

    // Loop, removing the first array item on each iteration
    while (attr = args.shift())
        this.removeAttr(attr);

    // Return the jQuery object for chaining
    return this;
}

$('#myImage').removeAttrs('class', 'style', 'border');
```

Here's one with a few different overloads, jQuery style:

```
$.fn.removeAttrs = function () {
    // Convert all passed arguments to an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        attr;

    // Handle passing arrays or space-separated strings
    if (args.length == 1)
        args = $.isArray(args[0]) ? args[0] : args[0].split(" ");

    // Loop, removing the first array item on each iteration
    while (attr = args.shift())
        this.removeAttr(attr);

    // Return the jQuery object for chaining
    return this;
}

// Now all of the following will work 
$('#myImage').removeAttrs(['class', 'style', 'border']);
$('#myImage').removeAttrs('class', 'style', 'border');
$('#myImage').removeAttrs('class style border');
```

Comment: Wow! this is super cool.. i just did the same thing like passing attrs as space-separated string.. getting an error there

Comment: Gottcha, i just need to split the first index of passed arguments :)

Comment: @Naresh: had a small error (calling `splice` instead of `slice` to convert the arguments) - I've updated it now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You already have a function in jquery

```
jQuery(element).removeAttr('attribute1 attribuite2 attribute3');
```

will remove all attributes in one go .

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/ here removeAttr can consume a list

Demo : just even for this very stackoverflow page in developer console do

jQuery('div#footer').removeAttr('id class')

This will remove both attributes id and class from the div

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this, SO HAPPY!

```
// classNames is an array of attribute names you want to remove from the element.
// jQueryElement is the jQuery element to remove the attributes from.
function removeSetOfAttributesFromAnElement(attNames, jQueryElement) {
    $.each(attNames, function() {
        jQueryElement.removeAttr(this);
    }
}

// call it!
removeSetOfAttributesFromAnElement(['class','style','border'], $("#myImage"));
```

Comment: Nice, can i call it like this? $('#myImage').removeSetOfAttributesFromAnElement(['class','style','border'])

Comment: @Naresh, you can probably hook-up the chaining functionality using the `$.fn` the namespace as Andy pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.
First ask is that really what you want to do. Bearing in mind you will loose the Id attribute.

But if you must what you could do is really create a new tag same as your source tag (DIV, etc) then get the source html using $('#target').html($('#source').html());

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding the question. My approach will rid the tag of all attributes.