# How to remove the attr() value on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I am using this code for set height and width for a image on mouseover

```
$('#gallery').find("img").attr('height', '20px');
$('#gallery').find("img").attr('width','20px');
```

//so here the default height and width are changed by the javascript above

When mouseout how to remove the height and width of the image set by the mouseover

Comment: Do you mean to reset them to the old value?

Comment: @AndreasWinter: yes reset to the old value

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870441/remove-all-attributes

Comment: And where would the 'old value' be kept?

Comment: @DavidThomas my answer below stores it in .data(). I think this would be a good place to store it in.

Comment: @d_inevitable, yeah; I meant where, in the initial html, would the values be found? (Would there be `width`/`height` attributes in the image, or would it just display at its default/'natural' size.)

Comment: @DavidThomas: it just display the default size no `width/height` attributes for the image

Comment: In which case there's no point storing the 'old' values, since on removal of the attributes they'll just revert back to their default size anyway.

Comment: @DavidThomas:yes you are exactly right.

Comment: @krish it is a good practice to set the width and height attributes in so that the layout can be predicted by the browser before the images are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hover()`:

```
$('#gallery').hover(
    function(){
        // mouseover
        $(this).find("img").attr({'height':'20px', 'width':'20px'});
    },
    function(){
        // mouseout
        $(this).find('img').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
        /* as of jQuery 1.7, it's possible to remove multiple attributes at once:
           $(this).removeAttr('height width'); */
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t3fYs/).

[JS Fiddle demo, using `.removeAttr('height width')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t3fYs/1/).

References:

- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Comment: from jQuery 1.7 you could also write `$(this).removeAttr('width height');`

Comment: Ah? I'd just been looking to see if multiple attributes could be removed in one `removeAttr()`, given that it seemed messy to use multiple calls to the same method. Thanks!

Comment: it may be worth memoizing `$(this).find("img")`

Comment: I think you should do a `.find("img")` on the mouse out too. Or, better `$("img",this)`.

Comment: @d_inevitable: you're absolutely right; I hadn't realised that I'd left that out. Thanks, and edited-in! =)

Comment: @jbabey: there's no point; I'm only using the `$(this).find('img')` once in each function, and storing that in the first function won't make it available to the second, so it wouldn't actually reduce the number of calls to either `$(this)` or `.find()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas oh right, hover takes two callbacks, i wrote that under the impression it took one.

Answer (score 1):

To restore previous values instead of reverting to default do this:

```
$("#gallery").mouseenter(function() {
   var gallery = this;

   $("img", this).each(function() {
      var prev = {
        "width": $(this).attr("width"),
        "height": $(this).attr("height")
      };

      var img = this;

      $(gallery).one("mouseleave", function() {
        $(img).attr(prev);
      });
   }).attr({'height':'20px', 'width':'20px'});
});
```

This will safely store the old value on a per-image basis, without conflicting with other images. (Even if each image has a different size to start with.

http://jsfiddle.net/4bEfs/

Answer (score 0):

on mouseout try 
`$('#gallery').find("img").attr('height', 'auto');
$('#gallery').find("img").attr('width','auto');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/hover/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/ in combination if you want to work on attributes.

A more flexible solution might be to manipulate css using http://api.jquery.com/css/. This way you can change multiple values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
on mouseover you store the width and height and later you restore them.

```
    var storeddimensions;    
    $('#gallery').hover( 
        function() {
            storeddimensions = new Array($(this).find("img").height(), $(this).find("img").width());
            $(this).find("img").attr({'height':'20px', 'width':'20px'}); 
        }, 
        function() { 
            $(this).find("img").attr({'height':storeddimensions[0] + 'px', 'width':storeddimensions [1] + 'px'}); 
        }
    );
```

Comment: Actually this will not work because there may be multiple images.