# How do I remove all tags in an input field below with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

How do I remove all tags in an input field below with jQuery?

```html
<input class="form-control" id="videotags" data-role="tagsinput"  placeholder="Video Tags" type="text">

  //what I tried:
<script>$("#videotags").remove();</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to clear input value or you want to remove input element from the dom ?

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Bootstrap `tagsinput` try this:

```
$("#videotags").tagsinput('removeAll');
```

[source](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
$('#videotags').tagsinput('removeAll');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#videotags').click(function() {
    var input = $(this);

    input.val('');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joe_hart/7xrg242b/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#videotags").replaceWith(function () {
return $('<' + this.nodeName +                   '>').append($(this).contents());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the targets of removing not tags but attributes?
The input tag in your question does not include tags.

If you want to remove all attributes in the input tags, I think you can use the method introduced in the below question.

[Remove all attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870441/remove-all-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-tags.js do not provide to delete All tags at once. I have tried some workarounds for this.
First I have fetch all the tags. Below is the code for that.

```
var tagData = $("#small").tags().tagData;
if (tagData.length > 0)
{
    $.each( tagData, function( index, value ){
      for(var tItem=0 ; tItem < tagData.length;)
      {
        $("#small").tags().removeTag(tagData[tItem]);
      }
     });
}
```

I have used 2 loops here as once you delete one record it will be reindex to 0.