# javascript, replace extra tags inside html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say you are given a messy string with this in it:

```
<b style="font-weight:normal;" id="docs-internal-guid-7304b159-0100-cc51-0691-8cd4685a5970">
 test
</b>
```

What's the simplest way to remove the extra style, id and so on inside html tags in Javascript?

So you would be left with:

```
<b>test</b>
```

Comment: *What's the simplest way to remove the extra style, id and so on inside html tags in Javascript?* what do you want actually ?

Comment: Added the expected result.

Comment: Is there a tag like `<b></b>` in HTML?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870441/remove-all-attributes

Comment: [<b>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b).

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex

```
/\s[^>]*>/g
```

> What this do,

Avoid the first `<b` opening tag and tag name and match till it's close `>` and replace it with `>`.

The `g` global flag is optional. If you have inner elements, it will be used.

Check the third snippet.

Thats it. All attributes are removed.

> But remember, Parsing HTML is not good.

```js
var a='<b style="font-weight:normal;" id="docs-internal-guid-7304b159-0100-cc51-0691-8cd4685a5970">test</b>';

a=a.replace(/\s[^>]*>/g,'>');
console.log(a);
```

If you want to get it from HTML, Then try

```js
a=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;

a=a.replace(/\s[^>]*>/g,'>');
console.log(a);
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML=a;
```

```html
<div><b style="font-weight:normal;" id="docs-internal-guid-7304b159-0100-cc51-0691-8cd4685a5970">test</b></div>
```

```js
a=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;

a=a.replace(/\s[^>]*>/g,'>');
console.log(a);
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML=a;
```

```html
<div><b style="font-weight:normal;" id="docs-internal-guid-7304b159-0100-cc51-0691-8cd4685a5970"><i class="iii">test</i></b></div>
```