# JSON Serialize two decimal numbers the same way

Tags: c#, serialization, formatting, json.net

How can I force the NewtonSoft Json Serializer to serialize two decimals numbers the same way?

```
decimal a = 1234.1200M;
decimal b = 1234.12M;

var sa = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { value = a });
var sb = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {value = b});
Console.WriteLine(sa);
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Results are:
{"value":1234.1200}
{"value":1234.12}

How can I force it to serialize them both with 4 decimals so the results are identical?

Comment: Bit of a hack, remove trailing zero's before the `M`. Good to see you on here +1

Answer (score 0):

You can format your decimal as follows:

```
        var sa = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { value = a.ToString("#.#000") });
        var sb = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { value = b.ToString("#.#000") });
```

Comment: But that's a string not a decimal. Your result will be `{"value": "1234.1200"}`. Also, that does not work when the decimal is part of a more complex object not just a simple version that I used in my example.

Comment: If you want to treat it as a decimal, there is no difference what so ever between "1234.1200" and "1234.12".  What you are requesting is a difference in the string representation. One could say, you are asking it to walk like a decimal and quack like a string...

Answer (score 0):

I found an "answer" after fiddling with the serializer a bit:

```
private class JsonTextWriterOptimized : JsonTextWriter
{
    public JsonTextWriterOptimized(TextWriter textWriter)
        : base(textWriter)
    {
    }
    public override void WriteValue(decimal value)
    {
        // we really really really want the value to be serialized as "0.0000" not "0.00" or "0.0000"!
        value = Math.Round(value, 4);
        // divide first to force the appearance of 4 decimals
        value = Math.Round((((value+0.00001M)/10000)*10000)-0.00001M, 4); 
        base.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

The first Math.Round will cut any decimals after the 4th.
The value+0.00001M is done so numbers like 100 become 100.00001. Then we multiply and divide. All that does makes the decimal stick to the 4 decimals. which we then round out to make sure the 5th decimal we added via the +0.00001 is gone.
This seems to work across any values I threw at it.

Then use the custom writer:

```
var jsonSerializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create();
var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
var sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriterOptimized(sw))
{
    jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, instance);
}
```

I also fixed my own answer (which I forgot about it to a similar question):
[Serializing a decimal to JSON, how to round off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283070/serializing-a-decimal-to-json-how-to-round-off/14729463#14729463)