# Need to round decimal variable to round up in 2 decimal place while serializing into JSON using JSON.NET in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, json.net, decimal

I've created a application in C# with SQL Server 2008 R2 backend. In my DB one of the table contains a column with datatype `money`. I'm using Entity Framework (Database First) to access data from the DB. In my EF Model, the `money` type attributed is represented as `decimal`.

Now when I serialize an object of that entity, that decimal property is represented as having 4 decimal places. I need this to have only 2 decimal places. I'm using `JSON.NET` to serialize my objects into JSON.

Here is what I'm getting (see the value of `Price` property)

```
{
  ID: 1,
  Name: "Product1"
  Category: 
    {
      ID: 1,
      Name: "Category1"
    },
  Price: 200.0000
}
```

Here is what I'm need (see the value of `Price` property)

```
{
  ID: 1,
  Name: "Product1"
  Category: 
    {
      ID: 1,
      Name: "Category1"
    },
  Price: 200.00
}
```

Is there any settings that I need to provide while serialization? Please give me any hint.

Comment: There are several points in the code at which you could do the rounding depending on how your retrieving your data before pushing it to the client. Can you provide a code sample of where you do this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283070/serializing-a-decimal-to-json-how-to-round-off

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus :: Oops.. Actually I didn't find this post, Anyway, thanks for the reference link.

Answer (score 0):

If in your db you see price being stored as

```
Price: 200.0000
```

then you can change your model get property to return only to 2 decimal place or if you can 
force database to store only 2 decimal places

```
decimal Price {get;set;}
```

you need to implement the get function to round to 2 decimal place