# Rounding in C#. Net

Tags: c#, rounding

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  The product of a calculation is 158 * 1.75 = 276.5.  I want this number to round up to 277.  I am using Math.Round but it rounds down.  I know I've seen this issue before somewhere.  What's the solution?

Comment: Refer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/in-c-math-round2-5-result-is-2-instead-of-3-are-you-kidding-me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8.aspx) that takes a [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx)

```
Math.Round(276.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

demo: http://ideone.com/sQ26z

Comment: It is interesting to note that if you use a format string to convert the number to a string representation with zero decimals, that is `string output = (276.5).ToString("F0");`, then the away-from-zero rule is also used. I don't think that the to-even rule is ever used when string formatting a number.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, you can use `Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`.

By default, .NET uses the so called [bankers rounding](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm) (or `MidpointRounding.ToEven`)

Answer (score 2):

.NET uses bankers' rounding by default; it rounds values ending in 5 to the nearest even significant digit, and not always up (called "semantic arithmetic rounding"). The reason is that if you round a bunch of random decimal numbers and then sum them, when using banker's rounding that sum will be closer to the sum of the unrounded numbers than the sum of arithmetically-rounded numbers would be.

To force it to use grade-school rounding rules, use the overload accepting a MidpointROunding enum value:

```
Math.Round(myNumber, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using Math.Ceiling instead

Comment: The OP (I am assuming) likely wants 276.1 to round to 276, not 277.

Comment: @NominSim...that is true 276.1 should be 276 and 276.5 should be 277