# C# midpointrounding down to zero

Tags: c#

I know about MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero and MidpointRounding.ToEven, but I think I want something inbetween. It is for a promotions module, so discounted prices must round down if the value is .5.

For example, I would like:

```
£1.244 to round to £1.24
£1.245 to round to £1.24
£1.246 to round to £1.25
```

As I understand it, .AwayFromZero would round the middle value to £1.25 and .ToEven would round correctly to £1.24, but £1.335 would be rounded to £1.34, rather than £1.33 which is what I want.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks, Jon

Comment: This SO question may be helpful... it looks like the default behavior to round towards whatever is even: http://stackoverflow.com/q/977796/945456

Comment: You could always use the mathematical modulus to check if the thousandth position is 5 or lower and round down, and 6 or higher to round up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of unspecified behavior.  Let's keep it safe and do the rounding explicitly, ignoring negatives since this is about money:

```
    public static decimal Promotion(decimal value) {
        decimal unround = decimal.Floor(value * 100m);
        decimal fraction = value * 100m - unround;
        if (fraction <= 0.5m) return unround / 100m;
        else return (unround + 1m) / 100m;
    }
```

Comment: Very useful! I'm surprised there isn't a "MidPointRoundDown" in the enum and that this code is even nescessary, but seems like Microsoft overlooked that. 
Here's a version with precision:
`private static decimal RoundDown(decimal value, int precision)
        {
            decimal factor = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
            decimal unround = decimal.Floor(value * factor);
            decimal fraction = value * factor - unround;
            return fraction <= 0.5m ? unround / factor : (unround + 1m) / factor;
        }`

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.ceiling(x - 0.5)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I thought about that, but these are item prices, so I didn't think it was an issue.  The OP would have to define how he wants to handle a price, say, of -1.5... if he thinks that situation will ever arise.  If so, it can be wrapped in a conditional:  x > 0 ? Math.ceiling(x-0.5) : <something else>;

Answer (score 0):

Ussually to do something like this you subtract .001 from your value, then round normally.

```
1.244 - .001 = 1.243 = 1.24
1.245 - .001 = 1.244 = 1.24
1.246 - .001 = 1.245 = 1.25

1.300 - .001 = 1.299 = 1.3
```

In this case, you REALLY want to put this in it's own function/extrension method, whatever, and document with a function WHY you subtract .001 before rounding.

Comment: What if your value is 1.245001?  In that case it would be rounded down, not up, the way it should be.

Comment: @Servy, we're talking currency for a promotion, which infers consumer currency (not crazy bank stuff with fractions of fractions of a cent), we probably don't need to worry about .000001 of a £.

Comment: You could get such a number as a result of floating point error (depending on data type) or as the result of division/multiplication.

Comment: @Servy, You should never be storing currency with floats, that's just asking for trouble.