# Rounding to 4 Decimal Places in C#

Tags: c#, decimal

I have the value

> 8443.64625

and want to round it to 4 decimal places. When I use `decimal.Round(8443.64625, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`it gives the value

> 8443.6463

. So it seems to be round up because of the 5. What can I do to make it return the value

> 8443.6462

.
I could convert it to string and then truncate after 4dp but I feel there has to be a more efficient way?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680121/c-sharp-midpointrounding-down-to-zero

Comment: What would you want `8443.64629` to be rounded to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suggested to use `decimal.Round(8443.64625, 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` by someone but that comment seems to have been removed.

`MidpointRounding.ToEven` works for the scenario I posted yes, but if the value was 8443.64629 it would produce 8443.6463. I need it to truncate without rounding.

I came across this answer which seems to truncate after 4dp with no rounding.

```
public static decimal TruncateValue(this decimal num, int significantDigits)
{
    decimal y = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, significantDigits);
    return Math.Truncate(num * y) / y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this it will work fine Just Try it once.
It will give You the result that you want.
that is 8443.6462.

```
    Math.Round(8443.64625, 4)
```

Comment: That actually rounds to the nearest EVEN number - try `Math.Round(8445.64635, 4)` - it will return `8445.6464` (which isn't what the OP wants, they want that to return `8445.6463`).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I want to return 8443.6462 which this seems to do

Comment: @BadDub But what do you want `8445.64635` to return? (This is not the same number as `8445.64625` - look at it carefully! One ends with `35` and the other with `25`.)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
var num = 8443.64625;

var roundedNum = Math.Round(num, 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Comment: It works for the scenario I posted yes, but if the value was 8443.64629 it would produce 8443.6463. I need it to truncate without rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has been answered yet but, you could use `Truncate`.

It's not 'rounding' per se but you would get the result I believe you want.

ie:

```
double num = 8443.64625;
Math.Truncate(10000 * num) / 10000
```

returns

```
8443.6462
```