# Decimal.Round default setting for MidpointRounding

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

The following applies:

```
var rounded = Decimal.Round(7.635m, 2);
//rounded: 7.63
```

This, to me, is wrong and unexpected behavior. I would assume the value of *rounded* to be **7.64**.

To achieve this, I can do:

```
var rounded = Decimal.Round(7.635m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
//rounded: 7.64
```

How can this **not** be the default behavior of `Decimal.Round`? Any good reason for this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/977807/525138, I don't think you can change the default.

Comment: I suppose they chose this as the default because most rounding on Decimals is done on currency. Unfortunately, it's also the default for double.Round(), which really royally stuffs a lot of mathematical calculations - especially ones to do with calculating pixel coordinates.

Comment: Does anybody notice that the default round-to-even **is rounding to odd in your example**?!! I have found this (mis?)behavior on one machine but not on another. Does anody know what's going on?

Comment: weird because in .NET Core `decimal.Round(7.635m, 2);` gives `7.64`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> How can this not be the default behavior of Decimal.Round? Any good
>   reason for this?

If you look at the documentation of [Decimal.Round Method (Decimal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2.aspx)

> The **behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4**.
>   This kind of rounding is sometimes called *round half to even* or
>   *banker's rounding*. It minimizes rounding errors that result from
>   consistently rounding a midpoint value in a single direction. It is
>   equivalent to calling the Round(Decimal, MidpointRounding) method with
>   a mode argument of MidpointRounding.ToEven.

Comment: This confirms the default, but does not add up with OP's first example. Why is it **rounding to odd**? I am encountering this behavior myself, irregularly, and I cannot explain it.

Comment: @Timo Can you supply examples of when this occurs?

Comment: @ErikKinding Been a year! I don't have examples anymore unfortunately. My machine produces `7.64` from `Decimal.Round(7.635m, 2)` as expected, I see. Does yours still produce `7.63`, as in your original post?

Comment: @Timo Actually no, when testing it out... Maybe they applied a patch? I'm getting 7.64 regardless of MidpointRounding.

Comment: 1.5 will round to 2, 2.5 will also default round to 2.
.5-Numbers will go to the nearest even number by default.

Answer (score 3):

From [`Math.Round(Decimal, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zy06z30k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Method

> The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This
>   kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's
>   rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently
>   rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.
>
> This method is equivalent to calling the Round method with a mode
>   argument of MidpointRounding.ToEven. If there is a single non-zero
>   digit in d to the right of the decimals decimal position and its value
>   is 5, the digit in the decimals position is rounded up if it is odd,
>   or left unchanged if it is even. If d has fewer fractional digits than
>   decimals, d is returned unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is they implemented a method following IEEE Standard 754, section 4.
This is called rounding to nearest or sometimes bankers rounding.

It's just one of many ways to do rounding and they choose this one.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankers_rounding

And for more information: [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)