# C# Alternative for Currency datatype in VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have project to be converted from VB to c#

In VB they are using Currency for a particular field.

It is rounding off to 4 decimal places but normal rounding is not happening

1.65555---->1.6555 
1.655551--->1.6556
Can anyone explain what rounding they are using or an alternative in c# ,Currently i am rounding off to 4 decimal places but its not getting the actual value in some cases

In default round 1.65555 is rounded off to 1.6556 not to 1.6555

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal.Round default setting for MidpointRounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405667/decimal-round-default-setting-for-midpointrounding)

Comment: Currency is not a default vb.net datatype. Please check which type is actually used (I'm guessing Decimal).

Comment: Currency is Jet/ADODB data type... in app I using decimal (`CDec`)

Comment: no its not the default datatype but i am using it.

Comment: That *is* normal rounding.   See the dupe link and the *Why* link there.

Comment: in default round 1.65555 is rounded off to 1.6556 not to 1.6555

Comment: Currency is a data type in VB6/VBA and Office Automation (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221223.aspx) and I suspect that this what you are referring to.  .Net does internally have the System.Currency structure (see:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#f33e5909d1d4c4d2), but you can not use it directly in VB.Net nor C#.  To get a Decimal variable to contain a Currency representation, you could do something like this:  `decVar=Decimal.FromOACurrency(Decimal.ToOACurrency(1.65555))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decVar=Decimal.FromOACurrency(Decimal.ToOACurrency(1.65555))

this was what i am looking for
Thank you @TnTinMn

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
    Math.Round([value], 4);
```

Comment: No it doesn't  round 1.65555---->1.6555

Comment: i thought 1.65555 -> 1.6556 was the desired result. Must have misunderstood.

Comment: You misunderstood. They explicitly state: `In default round 1.65555 is rounded off to 1.6556 not to 1.6555`. They need `Math.Floor()` not `Math.Round()`.