# Math.Round(((4.006+4.007)/2),3) = 4.006?

Tags: c#, math, double, average, rounding

Similar question, but without double and 3 decimal places.
The difference is that the average of two integers we may have a double as a result, but when we use (int) Math.Ceiling ((double) value), result an integer.
[C# - (int)Math.Round((double)(3514 + 3515)/2) =3514?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369664/c-sharp-intmath-rounddouble3514-3515-2-3514)

But in this case, we have two doubles and

```
Math.Round(((4.006+4.007)/2),3); // returns 4.006 

Math.Round(((4.008+4.007)/2),3); // returns 4.008
```

WHY?

Comment: The answer to the question you linked pretty much sums it up. `Math.Round` rounds to the closest **even** number, not to the closest number.

Comment: Rounding towards an even last digit is common practice. Did you explore the other rounding options, with the `Math.Round()` overloads?

Comment: Yes, I need to average two doubles ((x.xxx + y.yyy)/2), both with 3 decimal places.
When a double is even (x.xx(even)) and the other odd (y.yy(odd)), we will have as a result a double with 4 decimal places and the fourth digit is 5 (w.www5). So I need to round this double to 3 decimal places.

Comment: 1) use `decimal`, not `double`. double can't represent numbers like that exactly, leading to unexpected rounding behaviour. This includes adding an `m` suffix to literals 2) When the value is exactly in the middle, `Round` rounds to the nearest even value by default. Pass in `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` if you want to round up on `0.5`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN:

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Double The integer nearest a. If the fractional component
>   of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the
>   other odd, then the even number is returned. Note that this method
>   returns a Double instead of an integral type.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This
>   kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's
>   rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently
>   rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.

Also check this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c)