# Always Round UP a value in C#

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I want to roundup value according to the 3rd decimal point. It should always take the UP value and round. I used Math.Round, but it is not producing a result as i expected.

**Scenario 1**

```
var value1 = 2.526;
var result1 = Math.Round(value1, 2); //Expected: 2.53 //Actual: 2.53
```

**Scenario 2**

```
var value2 = 2.524;
var result2 = Math.Round(value2, 2); //Expected: 2.53 //Actual: 2.52
```

Scenario 1 is ok. It is producing the result as i expected.
In the 2nd scenario I have amount as 2.522. I want to consider 3rd decimal point (which is '4' in that case) and it should round UP. Expected result is 2.53

No matter what the 3rd decimal point is (whether it is less than 5 or greater than 5), it should always round UP.

Can anyone provide me a solution? I don't think Math.Round is helping me here.

Comment: If you're interested in decimal points, perhaps you should be using the `decimal` type rather than `double`? What kind of value are you trying to represent?

Comment: "but it is not producing a result as i expected." - to be honest, "always round UP" is not a result that many people expect.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that Math.Round is commonly misunderstood:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I come up with a solution. I improved Sinatr's answer as below,

```
var value = 2.524;
var result = RoundUpValue(value, 2); // Answer is 2.53

public double RoundUpValue(double value, int decimalpoint)
{
    var result = Math.Round(value, decimalpoint);
    if (result < value)
    {
        result += Math.Pow(10, -decimalpoint);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As Jon said, use a decimal instead. Then you can do this to always round up with 2 decimal points.

```
Math.Ceiling(value2 * 100) / 100
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Other answers might work, but this is th emost efficient. If you need it as a decimal/int, just convert it or cast it. But Math.Ceiling returns a double.

Answer (score 5):

```
var value2 = 2.524;
var result2 = Math.Round(value2, 2); //Expected: 2.53 //Actual: 2.52
if(result2 < value2)
    result += 0.01; // actual 2.53
```

Comment: This is correct according to the question i asked (round up value comparing 3rd decimal point).

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Math.Round(Value+0.005,2)
```

Comment: Note that you need to force mid-point rounding DOWN when doing this, otherwise a 0.000 could go *upwards*; and there is no "down" `MidpointRounding` mode...

Comment: @SonerGönül it's a pretty common trick; the ceiling version is better, though

Comment: looks like rounding to 2dp and always rounding up 3rd dp if 3rd dp > 0. Although that probably should be Value+0.005-EPSILON? O.o.