# Is there a C# function or overload to Math.Round that will allow abnormal rounding practices?

Tags: c#, rounding, math.round

I have the need to round a number for pricing sort of strangely as follows:

the value of an incoming price will be 3 decimal places (ie. 10.333)

It is necessary to round the first decimal place up if any number past said first decimal place is greater than 0.

for example:

```
10.300 = 10.3,
10.301 = 10.4,
10.333 = 10.4
```

before I go creating a custom method to do this I was wondering if anyone was aware of an existing usage/overload of Math.Round() or other already existing package to get this desired result?

Comment: This Question might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599118/always-round-up-a-value-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599118/always-round-up-a-value-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0#system-math-round(system-decimal-system-int32-system-midpointrounding)) has an overload that accepts a `MidpointRounding` enum value, which lets you specify the strategy for rounding.

In your case, you always want to round up, which is called `ToPositiveInfinity`.

```
Math.Round(yourValue, 1, System.MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach with `Math.Ceiling()`

```
decimal input = 10.300m;
decimal result = Math.Ceiling(input * 10m) / 10m;
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vck4Oa

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 10.300;
var result= Math.Ceiling((decimal)d * 10) / 10;
```