# TSQL Round positive and negative

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample input of `1.0950` with a float type.

Doing this for positive numbers is correct, with a `1.1` result

```
declare @x float
set @x = 1.0950
select round(@x, 1)
```

But when I change `@x` to negative `-1.0950` it still rounds to `-1.1` which is incorrect it should always round away from zero, so the answer should be `-1.09`

I would rather not do two statements, one for positive and one for negative.
If anyone could assist I would be very grateful!

Comment: If it should always round *away* from zero then surely `-1.1` is the right answer, as it is further from zero than `-1.09` ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put additional information. When negative -1.0950 it should round down to -1.09 but it's rounding up as it has .5. According to the ROUND documentation if positive it rounds up if negative it rounds down. This isn't happening for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Math.Round(2.5) return 2 instead of 3 in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c)

Comment: Actually, that *is* rounding down - it may seem counter-intuitive, but `-1.1` is less than `-1.09`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x float
set @x = -1.0950
select round(@x, 2)
```

Comment: That is correct for negative numbers. Then when the number is positive the result is 1.09, which is incorrect

Comment: 1.09 is correct when you round with 2 for positive number

Comment: Being positive it should be 1.1, when negative it should be -1.09. This makes sense when you're doing invoicing. I can do it with two statements but was hoping for one. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
declare @x float
set @x = -1.0950
select case when @x>0 then round(@x, 1)else ROUND(@x,2)end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax instead, it will add .005 and cast as decimal(18,2) getting the needed result:

```
SELECT x,cast(x + .005 as decimal(18,2)) val
FROM 
  (VALUES(1.0950),(-1.0950)) x(x)
```

Result:

```
      x     val
 1.0950    1.10
-1.0950   -1.09
```