# GWT - Rounding Mode with NumberFormat from com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat

Tags: java, gwt, number-formatting

I have a project where I need to format numbers before print them. I do it like that:

```
public String formatNumber(String format, long number, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(format);
    df.setRoundingMode(roundingMode);
    return df.format(number);
}
```

But my app need to use GWT, and I can't use DecimalFormat anymore because it's not supported. I need to use `NumberFormat` from the package `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;`.

I format my numbers like that:

```
public String formatNumber(String format, long number, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
     NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getFormat(format);
     return df.format(number);
 }
```

As you can see, df.setRoundingMode doesn't exist on NumberFormat. My number is automatically rounded to the nearest decimal. However, I do not always want to have this behavior. How can I round the numbers as I wish with this class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GWT `NumberFormat` does not support rounding modes. BUT, you are formatting a `long`, so looks like you don't need rounding anyway. If you really need it, so you have some `float`, `double`, `BigDecimal`, etc. I recommend that you use `BigDecimal` and change the scale before calling the formatter.

```
NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat().format(new BigDecimal(1.123).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

Or just...

```
String str = new BigDecimal(1.123).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `Math.rint()` and `Math.round()` [See difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257027/3193398)

You then would return `Math.rint(df.format(number))`