# Why does the decimal 2.5M round to 2?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, math

I must be missing some subtlety of .NET rounding. So I am looking at this example:

```
decimal num = 2.5M;
var result = Math.Round(num);
```

Why is `result = 2`? (I would have expected 3 since it should round up)

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3

Comment: ah yes, you are correct, I didn't see that question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want classic rounding use

```
        decimal num = 2.5M;
        var result = Math.Round(num,0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Comment: Somebody hit F1 on their visual studio :) Shortened the link for you without all the extra stuff the F1 adds on.

Answer (score 7):

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Decimal Math.Round(Decimald)
>
> Rounds a decimal value to the nearest integer, and rounds midpoint
> values to the nearest even number (example).

"Midpoint" here means `.5`; the even number in your case is `2`.  If you rounded `3.5` this way, it would result in `4`.

If you want to use "away from zero" rounding instead, you can use [the `System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
decimal d = 2.5M;
decimal roundedD = Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // results in 3
```

Regarding why it uses midpoint rounding (AKA "banker's rounding") by default instead of "away from zero" rounding, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311704/2704659).  Supposedly it's a better algorithm (i.e. more efficient over many iterations).

Comment: Why would they do it this way? This sounds counter to how rounding has been taught to me all these years.

Comment: so 4.5 would round to 4?

Comment: @Denis This is known as "banker's rounding". .5 is exactly in between the two whole numbers, so to always round up would bias your results higher than reality.

Comment: They did it so that statistically the total will be closer to the precise total. Imagine you do a sum of 100 rounded values. if about half of them are rounded up and half down, you will get a more correct total than if they all rounded up. My personal opinion - even though I understand this, I disagree with this, I think they should have used the standard rules.

Comment: never knew about "banker's rounding". Was just doing something simple and never thought the rabbit hole ran this deep.

Comment: It is called banker's rounding, it is the default rounding in IEEE 754 computing functions. It is designed this way so that the the average value of the rounded numbers is the same as that of the original numbers. For example round(2.5)+round(3.5)=6 instead of 7.

Comment: @Denis -- I stumbled across the very same thing a number of years back, and I was just as surprised.

Comment: @bib1257 *"I think they should have used the standard rules"*, if you are working in finance, that is the standard rules. That is why it is called ***Bankers*** rounding.