# Converting double to int returns unexpected results

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion, double, decimal

I want to show number conversion `double` to `int`. But I am confused. Here is my codes.

```
private void tbxDouble_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbxInt.Text = Convert.ToDouble(tbxDouble.Text).ToString("F0");
    tbxInt2.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(tbxDouble.Text),0).ToString();
}
```

Results for 100,5 =>
101 and
100

Results for 100,56 =>
101 and
101

Results for 100,49 =>
100 and
100

Why all results aren't 101? what is wrong with that?

Comment: Aw, comma is the English decimal point.  I feel very provincial for not seeing that immediately.

Comment: Yes according my os, comma is the decimal point. What is the problem Michael?

Comment: Why in your opinion `100,49` should be `101`?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to print the intermediate values instead of directly placing them into `ToString()`.  Seeing what exactly is coming from `Convert.ToDouble(tbxDouble.Text) would probably make things easier to see.

Comment: Ivan; i remember that; 100,49 ==> 100,5 ==> 101

Comment: @lotomax it will work as you've described only when you will first convert 100,49 to one decimal place and later to zero decimal places - if you want to convert to integer value in one step it will be 100

Comment: Ivan you are right 100,49 should be 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found mistakes. We shouldn't use Math.Round, because sometimes results are wrong. We should use like below:

```
tbxInt3.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(tbxDouble.Text), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
```

And here is the correct results:

Results for 100,5 => 101

Results for 100,56 => 101

Results for 100,49 => 100

[More information link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3/977807#977807)

Answer (score 7):

edit: As it was pointed in comments - my initial answer was wrong when I wrote that "F0" formatting will just truncate number. The correct answer is it will round but it will use other type of rounding called "Away from zero" rounding.

I assume cases with 100,49 and 100,56 are obvious, so let's take a look at 100,50

First of all let's take one step back: `Convert.ToDouble(tbxDouble.Text)` this line converted from string to double with value `100.50` and at this point you've done two different roundings.

First one:

```
value.ToString("F0");
```

is using Away from zero rounding

Second one:

```
Math.Round(value, 0)
```

is using Bankers Rounding

Bankers Rounding will round to the closest **even** number - so result will be 100. The Away From Zero rounding will round to 101 (101 is "more" away from zero than 100)

Comment: Why is "F0" returning 101? Your answer doesn't seem to explain it.

Comment: F0 just "cuts" decimal places - the results should be 100. there is no rounding here. Thanks for pointing out - I will edit my post to make it more clear

Comment: But if it cuts decimal, then why doesn't it return `100`?

Comment: This answer is wrong, how it's been upvoted 4 times is beyond me. "F0" does not truncate the number at all. It rounds the number as the other examples in the OP show. The issue here is that the rounding criteria doesn't seem to be the same as the one used by `Math.Round`.

Comment: @InBetween yes, you are right - my mistake - F0 does not truncate, it will use "AwayFromZero" rounding. My mistake was because of line in documentation saying "Note that the precision specifier controls the number of digits in the string representation of a number. It does not round the number itself." but I've missed next part: "When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result strings reflect numbers that are rounded away from zero (that is, using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you want to round to the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal   you have to use `Math.Ceiling` 
something like this

```
     class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double v2 = 100.56;
        double v3 = 100.49;
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(v2));
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(v3));

    }
}
```

Comment: result is; 101 and 101 and 100. I think it should be all of them is 101 as a mathematics rules?

Comment: According a math rules; it should be 101 - 101 - 100 ok?