# Rounding up and down by Math Round()

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have something like this:

```
double d1 = Math.Round(88.5, 0); // result 88
double d2 = Math.Round(89.5, 0); // result 90
```

Why is Math.Round() rounding even numbers down and odd numbers up?

Comment: It's using *banker's rounding*. Note that this is exactly [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_): "If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned."

Comment: Show this ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MidpointRounding parameter in Math.Round. 
When you're using Math.Round, one of its overload, is an overload which takes 2 parameters, the first one is your value and the second one is an enum of type MidpointRounding.

Consider code below:

```
Math.Round(88.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // The result is 89
Math.Round(88.5, MidpointRounding.ToEven) // The result is 88
```

Here is the MSDN documentation about Math.Round with MidpointRounding: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx 
And here is the documentation about the MidpointRounding:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx