# Rounding double variable

Tags: c#, math, double, rounding

I have the following problem. When I try to round a number from a "double" type, it doesn't work as I expect it.

Consider the following code:

```
double d = 0.00498;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(d, 2)); // prints 0
```

The result that i am getting is wrong.

The program must print 0.01, and I have tried everything and nothing worked properly.

Comment: Do you want to always round it up?

Comment: [Not an exact duplicate, but related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977807/3181933)

Comment: Come on guys.. have you ever been to forth grade, cant you see that the number is 0.01 ?!?

Comment: It surely will be 0 because you are rounding to 2 digit after decimal, make it .Round(d, 3) so it will become 0.005.

Comment: What's your exprected result at `double d = 0.00444449;`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a second iteration for your desired result

```
double d = 0.00498;
double result1 = Math.Round(d, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
double result2 = Math.Round(result1 , 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

because `0.00498` results into `0.005` instead of `0.01`

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it with only one iteration ?

Comment: @K.Krunk - why would you think there is a standard way to do non-standard math?

Answer (score 0):

You expect to it rounds the number up with 2 decimal points.

```
Math.Ceiling(d * 100) / 100
```

Comment: This will round `double d = 0.032;` to `0.04`

Answer (score 0):

The result is coming correct. You can try in excel application.

[image]

Regards,
Nandkumar S.