# Rounding Off a double value using Math.Round

Tags: c#, .net

I have a double value: 0.314285 which I want to Round off to 5 decimal places. From a mathematical point of view my expectant result is: 0.31429. In my code I use the Math.Round with `MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero` parameter overload, the resultant output being: 0.31428.

Is there another way to implement to have the output result as: 0.31429??

Comment: How did you declare the `0.314285` value? Basically, you should read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#rounding-and-precision) Using a decimal will solve your problem

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ This is related to `MidpointRounding`, `Round` uses `MidpointRounding.IsEven` by default, but OP explicitly sets it to `AwayFromZero`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the [rounding and precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#rounding-and-precision) article. The real representation of your number in memory can be something like `0.3142849999999999`, and therefore you are getting `0.31428` result. Using a [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) type can help to solve this issue

```cs
var value = 0.314285m;
var result = Math.Round(value, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //0.31429
```

Comment: Thank you very, yes i tried with a decimal type and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double RoundUp(double i, int decimalPlaces)
{
    var power = Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.Ceiling(i * power) / power;
}


RoundDown(0.314285, 5); //0.31429
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Math.Round(decimal number to round, int number of decimal places)
```

I think this should work for what you are trying to do.