# Rounding differences between decimal and double when formatting with ToString()

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am seeing differences in the result when formatting numeric values using `ToString("F2")`.

```
0.125m.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 0.13
0.125.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 0.12
```

Why are these values rounded differently?

.NET Fiddle version of the code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nF53LL).

Comment: [This .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DB63GG) prints `0.13` in both cases for .NET Framework.

Comment: @UweKeim for 4.7.2 not for [Core 3.1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYi3Ui)

Comment: Okay, when using .NET Core 3.1, [the .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nF53LL) has the same behaviour (`0.13` and `0.12`).

Comment: Yes the result is same same for .Net Framework 4.7.2 as well

Comment: seems like Framework is using MidpointAwayFromZero and in core is not  ... because it's [fine with 0,135](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xAzmRP)

Comment: I think the moral is: *always do your own rounding*, to be sure of what will happen.

Comment: Indeed, better [control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3) rounding..

Comment: Interesting, calling `Math.Round` manually and specifying 2 decimal places results in both being rounded the same: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SyJL4p

Comment: I'm definitely following @PeterB on this and rolling my own rounding function. I still can't get my head around why `decimal` and `double` would behave differently here though!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is due to how C# stores doubles/ decimals in memory that's leading to a floating point rounding error (same reason why 0.1 + 0.2 doesn't *exactly* 0.3 when calculating it in binary). Just haven't gotten around to testing it

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I'm reading that as explaining which rounding choice is made, but not why `double` and `decimal` would round differently. Am I missing something?

Edit: haha - I'm out of sync.  So, okay, it's the difference in precision that make the difference then.

Comment: I guess you have to look at binary presentation of `1.25`, it's probably *special*. Trying with `2.25` produces [same results](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tOUhQe).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - looks like that's right - `0.135` and both round to `0.14`.  Ahhh, computers and numbers... :(

Comment: @TimSchmelter - if you'd like to add an answer sometime, I'll tick the box!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings):

When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result string reflects a number that is rounded to a representable result nearest to the infinitely precise result. If there are two equally near representable results:

- On the .NET Framework and .NET Core up to .NET Core 2.0, the runtime selects the result with the greater least significant digit (that is, using `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`).
- On .NET Core 2.1 and later, the runtime selects the result with an even least significant digit (that is, using [`MidpointRounding.ToEven`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding#System_MidpointRounding_ToEven)).

Note that `double` is a floating binary point type. They are represented in binary system (like 11010.00110). When double is presented in decimal system it is only an approximation as not all binary numbers have exact representation in decimal system.