# C# Math.Round (1.785m, 2) not rounded correctly

Tags: c#, math, decimal, rounding-error

I’m experiencing a small issue when I’m trying to round the number `1.785m` to two digits. The number can probably not be represented correctly using the decimal data type, since it’s still a floating point number.

I would be excepting the result `1.79m` but it’s rounded/present as `1.78m`. My question is, how can I achieve a correct result?

My current workaround looks like this:

```cs
long l = (long)(1.785m * 1000m);
bool roundUp = l % 10 >= 5;

l = l / 10;

if(roundUp)
    l++;

decimal result = l \ 100;
```

Comment: I think what you're seeing is what's called "round to even" or "banker's rounding" in English. This question appears to be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3

Comment: You could do `Math.Round(1.785m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`.

Comment: "The number can probably not be represented correctly using the decimal data type, since it’s still a floating point number." It's a *decimal* floating point number though, so it can absolutely be represented correctly.

Comment: Note that the documentation for [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-8.0#system-math-round(system-decimal)) clearly explains that "rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number": 8 is even and 9 is odd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Math.Round(2.5) return 2 instead of 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explicitly set the [rounding mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0) to `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      double d, r;
      d = 1.785;
      r = Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
      Console.WriteLine(r); // 1.79

      d = -1.785;
      r = Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
      Console.WriteLine(r); // -1.79, not -1.78
    }
  }
}
```

But as per those code comments: this does exactly what it says on the tin for negative numbers, which will round down rather than up. If you need 0.5 to always round up you'll want `Math.ToPositiveInfinity`, but depending on your version of .NET, that enum may not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the third parameter to round as you want (cf. [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0#system-math-round(system-decimal-system-int32-system-midpointrounding))):

```cs
Math.Round(1.785, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 1.79
```