# Why does this arithmetic expression with the Math.Round return a wrong value?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

i have this C# snippet code. Someone can exaplain me why these expression using decimal variables return 2 different results?

```
decimal var1 = 6.75m;
decimal var2 = 13m;
decimal var3 = 30m;
decimal roundedResult1 = Math.Round(var1 * (var2 / var3), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
decimal roundedResult2 = Math.Round((var1 * var2) / var3, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

Console.WriteLine(roundedResult1); // 2.92
Console.WriteLine(roundedResult2); // 2.93
```

If I first divide var2 and var3 and finally multiply the result by var1 I obtain the result 2.924999999999998 (rounding with AwayFromZero I therefore obtain 2.92). If, however, I first multiply var1 and var2 and finally divide the result by var3 I obtain 2.925 as a result (rounding with AwayFromZero I therefore obtain 2.93). Why? Is there a way to get the same result as "roundedResult2" without necessarily changing the order within the expression?

I would have expected that even in the first expression the rounding result would always be 2.93!

Comment: Hint: look at 13 ÷ 30 in decimal.

Comment: _"Why?"_ - because result of `var2/var3` can't represented "correctly"/fully with floating-point numeric types (due to division by 3 of dividend which is not divisible by 3) and `decimal` is one of the floating-point types.

Comment: Floating point math isn't associative in general. Just as `a+(b+c)` does not equal `(a+b)+c`, the same applies to `(a*b)/c` and `a*(b/c)`. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Math.Round(2.5) return 2 instead of 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked:

> Is there a way to get the same result as "roundedResult2" without
> necessarily changing the order within the expression?

Yes.  You can try using:

```
decimal roundedResult = Math.Round(Math.Round(var1 * (var2 / var3), 4), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

If you were now to ask me:

> Is there a way to get the same result as "roundedResult2" without
> necessarily changing the order within the expression AND have it not
> appear SO UGLY?

Then I am at a loss.  Personally, I am a fan of using parenthesis, and given the known issues with division on floating point numbers, I would try to multiply first before dividing, which means using parentheses to enforce that order.  And it's less ugly than performing rounding twice.

**Why I favor Multiply First, Divide Second**

Two things guiding me are (1) floating points are approximations, and (2) division can introduce a teeny, tiny error in the operation.  If you divide first and multiply second, then you are AMPLIFYING that tiny error, and if the multiplication factor is large enough, then that tiny error can get amplified enough to make a significant difference (as you observed, and hence the reason for your post).  If you multiply first and divide second, then you have minimized the tiny floating point approximation.