# Inconsistency with Math.Round()

Tags: c#, rounding, trigonometry

I have two functions that are intended to contain angles between (-180,180] and (-π,π]. The intent is that given any angle from -inf to +inf it will retain the equivalent angle in the intervals specified. For example the angle for 1550° is 110°.

```
public double WrapBetween180(double angle)
{
    return angle - 360d * Math.Round(angle / 360d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
public double WrapBetweenPI(double angle)
{
    const double twopi = 2d * Math.PI;
    return angle - twopi * Math.Round(angle / twopi, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

which yields the following results

```
WrapBetween180(-180) = -180
WrapBetween180( 180) =  180

WrapBetweenPI(-Math.PI) =  Math.PI
WrapBetweenPI( Math.PI) = -Math.PI
```

none of which is what I want. What I wanted is:

```
WrapBetween180(-180) =  180
WrapBetween180( 180) =  180

WrapBetweenPI(-Math.PI) =  Math.PI
WrapBetweenPI( Math.PI) =  Math.PI
```

I tryied playing around with the rounding methods, but still cannot get the desired results. The problem is pronounced because sometimes the angles I deal with are only approximately close to -π or π and I am getting discontinuities it my results.

Any suggestions on how to best implement angle wrapping functions with non-inclusive low limit and inclusive high limits?

Comment: Every double supposed to be π is "only approximately close to π" :-)

Comment: What are these methods supposed to do? I can't see its purpose...

Comment: Are you saying you want really want the return of Math.Abs(value1);
where value1 is the result of your current functions?

Comment: Related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846911/net-round-bug/846917#846917.

Comment: @Stefan. I edited the question with an example of how these functions are supposed to work. Everything is ok, except when near the limits.

Comment: @Mark - No the sign discrepancy only occurs for one particular `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the angle in degrees, if `x` is between -180 and 180, then `180 - x` is between 0 and 360. What you want is equivalent to asking that `180 - x` is between 0 (inclusive), and 360 (exclusive). So, as soon as `180 - x` reaches 360, we want to add 360 to the angle. This gives us:

```
return angle + 360d * Math.Floor((180d - angle) / 360d);
```

Same thing for the angle in radians:

```
return angle + twopi * Math.Floor((Math.PI - angle) / twopi);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not address the rounding issue, but here is how I would to what you want to do :

```
private static double ConvertAngle(double angle)
{
    bool isNegative = angle < 0;
    if (isNegative)
        angle *= -1;

    angle = angle % 360;
    if (isNegative)
        angle = -1 * angle + 360;

    if (angle > 180)
        angle = (angle - 360);

    return angle;
}
```

*Note: This way supposes you want "behind" to be 180 degrees, not -180 degrees.*

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a case for a modulo operation?

```
private double Wrap180(double value)
{
    // exact rounding of corner values
    if (value == 180) return 180.0;
    if (value == -180) return 180.0;

    // "shift" by 180 and use module, then shift back.
    double wrapped = ((Math.Abs(value) + 180.0) % 360.0) - 180.0;

    // handle negative values correctly
    if (value < 0) return -wrapped;
    return wrapped;
}
```

It passes this tests

```
    Assert.AreEqual(170.0, wrap(-190.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(180.0, wrap(-180.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(-170.0, wrap(-170.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(0.0, wrap(0.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.0, wrap(10.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(170.0, wrap(170.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(180.0, wrap(180.0));
    Assert.AreEqual(-170.0, wrap(190.0));
```

Comment: I like the approach of using modulo, but I wonder how it performs relative to a `Math.Floor()` function for large numbers. Honestly I don't know which is the more robust approach.