# Math.Round() seems to be not consistent

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Round Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846911/net-round-bug)
>   [In C#: Math.Round(2.5) result is 2 (instead of 3)! Are you kidding me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/in-c-math-round2-5-result-is-2-instead-of-3-are-you-kidding-me)

Code:

```
var d1 = Math.Round(187.5); // 188
var d2 = Math.Round(62.5); // 62
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, `Math.Round` uses a form of rounding called [Banker's Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), which rounds to the nearest *even* integer when the input is halfway between two integers.

See [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default) for an understanding of this design decision.

If you don't like this behaviour, you can always use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8.aspx) of `Math.Round`, which lets you specify the `MidPointRoundingMode` (ToEven, AwayFromZero).

Comment: @Joey: Please refrain from editing posts just after they have been posted, especially during the edit window. Thanks.

Comment: It's technically possible; the post was lacking in information and plenty of answers remain that way even after the edit window. You can either revert or override the changes which you did in this case anyway, so where was the harm in what I have done?

Comment: @Joey: You could wait for a while since there is a good chance that a post is being edited during the edit window. In this case, I didn't actually 'override' - it was actually a case of clashing edits.

Answer (score 2):

You can change this behaviour with an call to this overload of the method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx